# Converting 3DS max camera parameters to blender

Tags: camera

My current workflow on a couple of projects is

1. Creating a camera in 3DsMax using "Camera match" matching an existing 3D scanned model onto a photograph.
2. Creating an identical camera in Blender using the same parameters as the 3DSMAX camera.
3. Corporate 3D models into the 3D scanned model using Blender.

My problem is that for step 2, I need to do adjust some parameters (LENS and FOV values) manually using my eyes, since I don't know how to translate them into Blenders camera. Using the same Lens and Fov values that's in the 3DsMAX camera will yield a camera in Blender that's not matched to the model at all.
I would like to find a solution where the camera can be converted to Blender just using numbers. Does anyone know if there are some other parameters other than "Rotation", "position", "FOV" and "Lens" that needs to be involved for this task.
Thank you for any answer and have a great day!

The sensor size in blender (auto value = 32) is indeed affecting the camera match. But I have no idea on how to get info on the sensor size in the 3DS Max camera. Maybe it's hidden in some panel. I find nothing when looking through the manual.

Comment: If the camera's lens is not matching it might be because the sensor size is not the same. In other words the same lens size will have different FOV on different size sensors.

Comment: http://www.designimage.co.uk/3dsmax_filmback/. If that helps please write your own answer to help others with a similar queryy.